# Expanded row equal to size of 3 columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-grid

I am a newbie in developing the layouts and wondering if someone can help me point to the right direction in building a dashboard UI page that looks like this:

[image]

I tried bootstrap, reactstrap, and played with the flex as well. The issue I am running into is when creating box 6, 7, 7, and 9.

I have bunch of sample code, but the one with the flex is:

```
.box {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box>* {
    flex: 1 1 80px;
}

 <div class="box">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div>Five</div>
    <div>Six</div>
    <div>Seven</div>
    <div>Eight</div>
    <div>Nine</div>
    <div>Ten</div>
  </div>
```

I am open to adopting any new tool that can help me achieve this, but priority is to use reactstrap or bootstrap or something similar.

Comment: Why a down vote, what is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2):

One way is use css [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

CSS:

```
.box {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.six{
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
    grid-column: 1 /4;
}

.nine{
   grid-column: 5 /5;
     grid-row: 2 / 5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div>Five</div>
    <div class="six">Six</div>
    <div>Seven</div>
    <div>Eight</div>
    <div class="nine">Nine</div>
    <div>Ten</div>
    <div>Eleven</div>
    <div>Twelve</div>
    <div>thirteen</div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/hans-felix/pen/eYpjJoB